# MSChart - How can i add an on click event to my title?

Tags: c#, mschart

so i have my title:

```
    Chart = CreateChartTemplate();
    Title area1Title = new Title(chartTitle, Docking.Top, new Font("Verdana", 12),      Color.Black);
    area1Title.IsDockedInsideChartArea = false;
    area1Title.Docking = Docking.Top; 
    Chart.Titles.Add(area1Title);
```

i'd like to add an onclick event to it. I've researched it and googled it but i've found mostly things about datapoints i get quite confused when it comes to using the sender arg. I have used it before but only for buttons, so i could assign it using button.Click+= methodname.
i plan on using the on click event to pop up a dialog box of sorts which will allow a user to change the title.

should probably add that this is not for a web based chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no events for `Title` class. But you can check where the mouse click has happened and display the user input dialog if the click is on a title.

Subscrible to the chart's `MouseDown` event.

```
chart1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(chart1_MouseDown);
```

In the event handler check whether the click is on the title and show the dialog from user input.

```
void chart1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult result = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.Title)
    {
        Title aTitle = result.Object as Title;
        if (aTitle != null)
        {
            // show dialog for user input.
            aTitle.Text = //user input value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HitTestResult result = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y); This line gets the cursor co-ordinates then?

result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.Title and this line checks whether those co-ordinates land on the title?

+1 for now i'll check it out today Thanks!

Comment: The cursor co-ordinates are already obtained from the `MouseEventArgs`. The HitTest method checks where the mouse click happened in the chart area and the CharElementType check whether the click is on title.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I prefer being able to understand over blindless copy and paste :P